# understanding self.including in ruby

Tags: ruby, module

Suppose I have

```
module Mod
  def self.included(base)
      some_method
    end
  def some_method
  end
end

class A 
  include Mod
end
```

I get `some_method` is not defined. So how can call `some_method` as soon as `Mod` is included ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `included` method is called on class level, when the module is included into a class and `some_method` is called on class level too. Therefore `some_method` needs to be a class method to be found. This will work (note the `self.some_method`):

```
module Mod
  def self.included(base)
    some_method
  end
  def self.some_method
  end
end

class A 
  include Mod
end
```

Or you need to create an instance of your base class first and call `some_method` on that instance like @ArupRakshit mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 8):

You have to create a `base` class instance to call it.

```
module Mod
  def self.included(base)
      base.new.some_method
  end
  def some_method
  end
end

class A 
  include Mod
end
```

After *including* module `Mod`, `some_method` will be available as instance method of the instances of class `A`.

Answer (score 0):

As it has been told by spickermann that `:included` method is called on class level when module is being included into a class, same way `:some_method` needs to be called on class level too as it is being called from `:included` method, we can use `base.class_eval` as `class_eval` can be used to add methods to a class.

```
module Mod
  def self.included(base)
      base.class_eval do
        some_method
      end
    end
  def some_method
  end
end

class A 
  include Mod
end
```

Here you can do the following with `:some_method`

```
A.some_method
#=> nil 
A.new.some_method
#=> nil
```